# How to Check the Integrity of a SQL Server Backup File?

Tags: sql-server, file, backup, data-integrity

In Microsoft SQL Server is there a way to test the integrity of a database backup file without having to restore it to see if it works?

I've looked through the SQL Server 2014 Management Studio UI and don't see a Test option exposed there.

I've filtered through the [Restore Options page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms188223.aspx) and haven't been able to pinpoint anything useful there.

Also I've done some searching on the Internet. Maybe it's due to the generic wording of the search items but I haven't come up with anything yet except how to restore databases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188902.aspx

Restore verify only, verifies the backup but does not restore it

---

Also available in SQL Management Studio UI as a button.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I had been Googling for 'test' instead of 'verify'. Also I found the option you described in Management Studio (it was sitting in front of me all the time) and posted a screenshot of that to the answer.